# Powershell: ssh command from bash to powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh, powershell-2.0, minikube

I want to map docker-machine's 5000 to the host's 5000. The command below works in bash but not in the PowerShell.

```
ssh -i ~\.docker\machine\machines\default\id_rsa -R 5000:localhost:5000 docker@$(docker-machine ip)
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Rpvv.png)

Comment: What happens when you run the command in powershell? Do you get an error message? What does it say?

Comment: I get this error message: The term 'ssh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: The error means that the `ssh` command is not found in the `Path`. Either prefix the `ssh` program file's directory before its name or add the `ssh` program's directory to the `Path`.

Comment: Thank you. I have added a screenshot of the full error. Does this still fit your solution?